# How to use return key and emojis on the same keyboard on Android?

Tags: android

On my layout I added a EditText and I use textShortMessage to show emojis. But when I use this option the keyboard don't show "return key". If I use textLongMessage the return key is showed and a long press, show emojis key.
But I would like to show on emojis and return key option together. Is possible for example show emojis on the same key that give option to change to number or symbols? in the key "?123" Or show a key only to change emojis without hide the return key?

Comment: did you ever find a way?

Comment: No. I can't do it

Answer (score 0):

I did tests and the verion of android define it. So I use "textShortMessage" and work very well